# Javascript Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

Hello I am having a problem with this line of javascript, I am a complete beginner and I am struggling with passing parameters in. All I need to do is change a label in my HTML file with passed parameters but I receive:

```
Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference
```

Can someone please help? I have searched other questions but they do not help me with my problem.

```
function changeLabel(id, text){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}

changeLabel('label1', 'mylabel1');
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="content1">content 1</div>
         <div id="content2">content 2</div>
         <form id="form1">
            <label id="label1">Form Label1</label>
            <input id="myText" type="text" value="A Text Field">
         </form>

      </div>
```

Comment: Is there an element with id mylabel1? Also your code does not make much sense, I think the 1st argument of your changeLabel function should probably be called id...

Comment: I would change your function signature to `function changeLabel(id, text) { document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text; }`

Comment: `id` is undefined obviously.

Comment: Do you have an element in your page that has an id `label1`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using correctly the arguments you passed in the function. I think your real intent was:

```
function changeLabel(mylabel1, label1){
    document.getElementById(mylabel1).innerHTML = label1;
}
```

EDIT:

According to you new code, the usage should be:

```
changeLabel('mylabel1', 'label1');
```

Comment: Yes that is my intent, however this is not working. I need the text in label1 to change to "mylabel1". Can you help?

Comment: I see you have changed your buggy code. The new code looks better but both arguments are inverted.

Comment: What do you mean by they are inverted? Are they in the wrong order?

Comment: Sorry yes my mistake

Comment: This code has the same error as originally:

function changeLabel(mylabel1, label1){
    document.getElementById(label1).innerHTML = mylabel1;
}

changeLabel('mylabel1', 'label1');

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you call the function before you load HTML file and the browser try to change html element during changeLabel() execution while HTML element is not loaded yet.
Try to paste your javascript code:

```
<p id="label1"></p>
<script>
function changeLabel(id, text){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}
changeLabel('label1', 'mylabel1');
</script>
```

after/under your HTML element in your .html file or if you load external javascript file with this code use:

```
window.onload = function() { //changeLabel() will be executed after page load
    function changeLabel(id, text){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
    }
    changeLabel('label1', 'mylabel1');
};
```

You can also load your external javascript file at the end of your html file.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
    //context
    </body>
  <script src="myexternaljs.js"></script>
</html>
```

then you don't have to use:

```
window.onload = function() {};
```

Comment: If I put this at the end of my javascript file, I receive this error:

Comment: ReferenceError: 'changeLabel' is undefined

Comment: Try wrapping all your code in `window.onload = function() {` and `}` ? @JamesB